# How to allow only numbers and format value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to know how to validate the text field that allows only numbers and then format the value in javascript.

How to validate the input text by not allowing to paste,ctrl,shift, backspace and del and not allowing special charaters and alphabets,

```
 <input name="samount" type="text" id="samount" class="form-control"
  @keyup=${this.formatCurrency}>


formatCurrency(e){
  var myinput = e.target.value;
      var val = myinput;
      val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');      
      if(val != "") {
        var valArr = val.split('.');
        valArr[0] = (parseInt(valArr[0],10)).toLocaleString();
        val = valArr.join('.');
      }      
      e.target.value = val;
      this.rateValue();
}
```

```
Should allow only numbers
```

Comment: Use input type as number...

Comment: As a user I would simply plainly HATE you for not allowing me to type instead of just complaining and telling me what's the problem if I'm typing something wrong. It would be like talking to someone that at every single word interrupts you. Not allowing backspace should be considered a crime having your programming license revoked on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Keyup event contains the key typed, make a test on it (if parseInt or dot ...).

Answer (score 0):

*try to update your regex expression and use match function in the if condition to check whether your field values are matching with the regrex.
* **every key has it seperate keycode u can validate using that keycode to mention that this key doesn't work on this text field**

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to delete the input value on keyup when it is not numeric.

```
$("#myinput").keyup(function(e) {
        if($(this).val().match(/^[0-9]+$/))
            return;
        else
            $(this).val('');
});
```

Alternatively check for `e.keyCode` and prevent input when it does not match the ranges `48-57` and `96-105`(numpad has separate keycodes)